# Bundle up middlewares into one async error handler in express js (central error handling)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, middleware

I have set up api end points like the following

```
// doesn't require to go through auth middleware
app.get('/api/list', asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res) => {
   // stuffs here
   if (somethingWrong)
       throw new Error("Something is wrong for sure")
   else 
      res.status(200).send("Only List for you okay?")
}, false))

// requires to go through auth middleware
app.get('/api/show', asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res) => {
   // stuffs here
   if (somethingWrong)
       throw new Error("Something is wrong for sure")
   else 
      res.status(200).send("Here you go my dude! wink")
}))

// auth function 
const auth = async (req, res, next) => { 
   //stuffs here
   if(notProperUser) throw new Error("Bruh! You not supposed to be here!") 
   else next()

}
```

How do I set up my `asyncErrorHandler` so that the following things occur in the block?

```
const asyncErrorHandler =  (fn, authParam = true) => (req, res, next) => {
    
   // if authPram = true
   // promise resolve auth then = > fn = > if error is thrown, 
   // catch error and break promise chain
   // log e and return res.status(e.status).send("error") 
   // (assume we have a custom error with status)
   // else
   // same as if block but skip auth and only execute fn callback function 
   // need to be executed
}
```

Cannot use the following

```
app.get('/api/show', auth, asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res) => {
   // stuffs here
   if (somethingWrong)
       throw new Error("Something is wrong for sure")
   else 
      res.status(200).send("Here you go my dude! wink")
}))
```

Because error thrown at `auth` layer won't be caught by `asyncErrorHandler`. Error at `auth` needs to get caught by `asyncErrorHandler` as there needs to be central error handling of all layers.

I want to know how we can accommodate the `authParam` flag and extra `auth` middleware with something like the following

```
const asyncErrorHandler =  (fn, authParam = true) => (req, res, next) => {
  
  // following code is incomplete - MISSING
  // authParam check and based on that
  // resolve auth and fn TWO promises sequentially
  // if auth throws error fn should NOT execute
  // and error at auth needs to be caught
  // then sent to the client
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch((e) => {
        res.status(e.status).send("Error")
    })

}
```

How can I do something like above that will check `authParam` and based upon that resolve `auth` and `fn` accordingly? What changes would the above code require?

Comment: For starters, your callback is `async` so it will return a promise and when you `throw` in it, it will reject that promise.  So your `asyncErrorHandler` function needs to be paying attention to the promise that your callback returns and handling both resolve and reject of that promise.  Not sure what else you're trying to ask.

Comment: @jfriend00: updated the question about what exactly I want to solve. I need to handle two promises properly and sequentially while catching errors occurring at either of the promises.